# How can I display the rest of a file starting from a matching line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to display a line matching a search term and all the remaining lines in the file.

For example, if I use:

```
more text.txt | egrep show
```

it will only show the line that has "show" in it, while I would wish for something like a `start` command:

```
more text.txt | start show
```

that will show all the lines after the first line that matches the search term.

However, it's not working on my Ubuntu. How can I install it or anything similar to it?

Comment: Do you have any link to a description of that syntax, or is it just something you would like to have ? I can't find any command `start` in Ubuntu. And what comes directly after the pipe sign must be a command.

Comment: One very crude way would be to do `grep -A 10000 show text.txt`, showing the line containing `show` and 10000 lines after it, which would work if your file is less than 10000 lines.

Comment: @SorenA , it is something I want to achieve, a keyword and show everything after it, trim everything before it

Comment: @Jos, that is a great workaround, thanks, but if I found such a command it would be awesome
or if we can craft a script for it!

Comment: @Jos, very good suggestion which deserves to end up in an answer. Make an alias, e.g. `alias start="grep -A 10000"` to have your single command. No need to pipe.

Comment: If you're using `more` *as intended* (as a pager, rather than a substitute `cat`) then you could use `more +/show text.txt` or `less +/show text.txt` to skip immediately to the matching text.

Comment: sed and awk are definitely better suited to this job, and more elegantly resolve the problem (in a portable way across most unixes)  instead of a clever tweak on a gnu-grep only option (-A) ...

Comment: btw, welcome to askUbuntu. It is good orzctice yo wait a day or 2 before accepting the best answer, as often the first few solutions fiven, while working, may not be the best way to solve the problem (some people only look at questions after several hours or days , and they could possibly have the best (elegant and portable and flexible) answer, or sometimes they refine it over a period of time before (or after) submitting it)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your file is less than, say, 10000 lines, you can do this:

```
grep -A 10000 show text.txt
```

The `-A` flag will show the line containing the search string (`show`) and the next 10000 lines.

However, I played around with the `-A` flag a bit, and I noticed `grep` will intelligently combine the output, so you don't get 10001 lines for each time the string `show` is found. So basically, it will show you the whole file once, starting from the line that contains `show`. If your file contains more than 10000 lines, adjust the parameter appropriately.

You can use the `alias` command to create your own custom command to achieve the same result.

EDIT: a slightly more elegant solution would be to use

```
 grep show -A $(wc -l < text.txt) text.txt
```

which will use the actual length of the file as the `-A` flag. This requires you to specify the file name twice. Unfortunately this will prevent the use of an alias, but you could write a shell function to do this.

Apparently, in this case you need to specify the search string first to avoid an error.

Comment: +1 :) `-A` for After, `-B` for before if you want to see lines before the match.

Comment: "This requires you to specify the file name twice (which certainly calls for an alias).": that is where an alias won't cut it anymore - a bash function could be used.

Comment: @vanadium yes, you are right. I never use aliases but assumed you could enter a parameter here or there, but you can't. I will modify my remark.

Comment: `wc -l text.txt` will output `count filename` `wc -l < text.txt` is probably what you want

Comment: @bac0n Agreed. Amended

Comment: I have created this alias, and it's working fine now, thanks Jos

Comment: "…noticed grep will intelligently combine the output"

Note that there's nothing *intelligent* there per se; this is simply the only way grep can work because it only does a single pass through the file (although I guess that could be called a feature). So essentially it displays up to *n* lines, or until the end of the file, or until the next match is found, whichever comes first. And in the latter case it then resets the counter to zero and continues displaying context lines.

Comment: Note that you can shorten your grep command to `grep show -A $(wc -l text.txt)`, since `wc` prints the file name, you don't have to pass it to grep manually. The only downside of this is handling names that require quoting

Comment: @Ferrybig Ah, clever!

Comment: @JohannesD thanks for this addition. I called it "intelligent" as opposed to a "naive" way of simply showing every line containing the search string plus the n subsequent lines, regardless of whether these lines contained the search string or not, possibly yielding duplicates. The use of a counter is, of course, an obvious improvement.

Comment: General remark: This is not an Ubuntu-specific question, but a general UNIX/Linux one.

Comment: The disadvantage of using `grep` with `wc` for this is that it needs to redundantly read the input whole once before it can start matching, so 1) if the input is large, it would waiting before seeing any result even if the first line matches, and 2) this wouldn't work with piped input.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't particularly need grep, you could use `sed` or `awk` for this:

```
sed -n '/show/,$p' text.txt
awk '/show/ {display=1} display {print}' text.txt
```

- `sed` usually outputs all lines, but `-n` prevents that.
  `/show/,$` is a line-range starting at the first line matching the regular expression `show` and ending at the last line (`$`).
  The print (`p`) command prints that line-range.
- `awk` uses sequences of `condition { action }` pairs (usually on separate lines for readability), so `/show/` is the condition that matches the regular expression `show` anywhere in an input line, and `display=1` defines a variable named `display` to `1`.
  Obviously condition `display` is a short form for `display != 0`, and `print` does what everyone expects, i.e.: print the input line.

Comment: those 2 are more elegant and also more portable as they don't depend on a gnu version of grep (-A option to grep is not posix)

Comment: The awk code can also be short: `awk 'd=d||/show/'`.

Comment: Actually I wanted to suggest `echo '/show/,$p' | ed -s text.txt`, but using `sed` is even easier!

Comment: @JoL You could add this as an answer with some explanation!

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog @JoL So does `awk 'var=var || /show/'`... The idea is to evaluate `/show/` only once and print that line... then make `awk` assume it is true after that and print the remaining lines without evaluating..."If the value of the entire expression `var=var || /show/` is determinable from evaluating just the lefthand side of `||`, the righthand side is not evaluated."... This is the nature of the awk logical operators.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Raffa's use of whitespace is a little misleading. The precedence of `=` is lower than `||`, so the expression is evaluated as `var=(var || /show/)`. The assignment operator `=` returns the value of the right-hand side, and unassigned variables are falsy. Finally, there's no accompanying action for that matching condition because the default is `{print}`, which is what we want.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '/show/,0' text.txt
```

Awk allows specifying a range `condition-expression , condition-expression`, where the action-code is evaluated for each line between where the first condition returns true, until the second condition returns true.

By using constant false `0` as the second condition, the default action `{ print }` will run for the matching line and every line after that.

In case you want to define your `start` command, `awk` allows passing string variables, so here you go:

```
start() {
  awk -v regex="$1" '$0 ~ regex, 0' "${@:2}"
}
```

`$0 ~ regex` is used to match a string as if it were a regex. `$0` in awk refers to the whole line. `"${@:2}"` is all command arguments after the first one if there are any. That way, you can optionally specify files to `start`, or else let it read from piped input.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```bsh
word="show"
e=0

while read line
do
    [[ $line =~ "$word" ]] && e=1
    [ $e -eq 1 ] && echo "$line"
done < text.txt
```

That can be added as a function to `~/.bashrc` like so:

```bsh
grep2end () {

word="$1"
e=0

while read line
do
    [[ $line =~ "$word" ]] && e=1
    [ $e -eq 1 ] && echo "$line"
done < "$2"

}
```

and used like so:

```
grep2end "show" "text.txt"
```